# Which would be calculated first?

Tags: c

Only 3 days while learning C. Noticed this in the book:

```
int main() {
  int x = 10, y = 15;
  if (x % 2 == y % 3) {
    printf("Which one x%2 or y%3 calculated first");
  }
}
```

My question is in if condition. Question is which expression is calculated first, x%3 or y%3?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Unrelated side note: When you've studied only for 3 days, you might want to focus your efforts to something else other than insignificant trivia like this.

Comment: @JJJ I don't know if operator precedence can be considered "insignificant trivia".

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's not what I said. This isn't a very good example of operator precedence and about as far removed from reality as you can get. From the past 20 years of programming I can't recall a single incidence where it made any difference which side of equality comparison was evaluated first.

Comment: Nor do I see how operator precedence has anything to do with the OP's question. The question isn't about precedence; its about order of eval. There are *seven* expressions in that conditional (four of which are arguably trivial). The question is about two of those expressions, and their order of their evaluation.

Comment: @JJJ Understanding that the equality has lower precedence than most operators is important. Of course once you understand that, it's obvious.

Comment: @JJJ If you didn't mean that operator precedence is insignificant trivia, sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: Not to be picky here, but `x % 3` will never be calculated in the example. :)

Comment: There is another option.  The compiler may optimize out the entire expression.

Comment: @JJJ already stated it clear. This is neither a question of operator precedence, nor operator associativity. It concerns order of evaluation of operator arguments, which is undefined in C. So this is a bogus problem. The order is implementation dependent and generally not of interest.

Comment: BTW Use `%%` instead of `%` in the format string of `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: C does not specify which of `x % 2` and `y % 3` is computed first, and since there is no side effect in either sub-expression, it does not matter.

The long answer is: Actually, looking at the generated code on [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/F5ZYqJ), the expression may be evaluated at compile time and none of these are computed at runtime.

Very few C operators have a specified order of evaluation:

- the comma operator `,`
- the logical and `&&` and logical or `||` as well as the ternary operator `?` `:` (they actually only evaluate their second or third operand if the first has a specific truth value).
- function arguments are evaluated before the function is called, but their relative order of evaluation is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

I is a tricky question and it was very popular during the interviews some time ago.

If I make it this example a bit less trivial and avoid optimisations:

```
int comapare(int x, int y) {

  int result;
  if (result = (x % 2 == y % 3)) {
    printf("Which one x%%2 or y%%3 calculated first");
  }
return result;
}
```

The order of evaluation of this particular is undetermined as only logical operators are guaranteed from the left to the right and evaluate the smallest number of operands needed to determine the result of the expression. Operator `==` along with all other comparison operators ***is not*** the logical operator.

Most interviewed candidates answered that it will be evaluated from the left to the right as it is the logical operation.

Answer (score -4):

It's a good question Gaurav. Always have that inquisitive mind as that's how you can attain true learning.

As suggested in the comments, this question relates to Operator Precedence and Associativity.

[Here you can get an idea in general.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

[Here, it's more specific to your question](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). As you can see there (point# 3),  for `%` operator, it is from Left-to-right.

It is important to distinguish here between how equality == works versus the assignment operator = as the later works from right-to-left. As mentioned in that link, for the assignment operators like `=`, the expression `a=b=c` is parsed as `a=(b=c)`, and **not** as `(a=b)=c` because of right-to-left associativity.

Hope this will clear your doubts!

**Additional clarifications:**

Based on subsequent discussions in the comment section, I feel it necessary to remove some of the confusions.

- Confusion about operator associativity and order of evaluation:

  If two operators are of same precedence, Associativity of operators determines the order in which they execute. The associativity of `==` is left to right, i.e, the expression on the left is executed first and moves toward the right. So answer to the question of which expression is calculated first in the equation `x % 2 == y % 3`, the answer would be like this:

  1. evaluation of `x % 2`.

  2. evaluation of `y % 3`.

  3. evaluation of `==`
- Do compilers strictly follow this rule?

  Not necessarily. The compilers are free to evaluate such expressions in any order, if they can guarantee a consistent result. Only the sequential-evaluation (,), logical-AND (&&), logical-OR (||), conditional-expression (? :), and function-call operators constitute sequence points and therefore guarantee a particular order of evaluation for their operands.
- Authentic reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Comment: You're confusing operator associativity and order of evaluation. The latter is usally undefined in C, so it's implementation dependent.

Comment: @SBS: order of evaluation is implementation dependent but not implementation defined.  The same compiler may generate code that evaluates the same expression in a different order in different places, at different times, for different runs...

Comment: @chqrlie Exactly.

Comment: hi SBS & chqrlie, thanx for raising pertinent questions. i have added clarification accordingly